# Convert String to ArrayType in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Using spark_read_json a String column was created that contains a jsonArray. How can I convert the string in sparklyr, so that the datatype changes from string to Array?

Array is the following form:

```
[{\"ItemId\":\"27CF083F-F7CD-2574-7D27-FEBE846A74C9\"}]
```

Using sdf_schema_json I find out the following:

```
$type
[1] "struct"

$fields
$fields[[1]]
$fields[[1]]$name
[1] "CalculationList"

$fields[[1]]$type
[1] "string"

$fields[[1]]$nullable
[1] TRUE

$fields[[1]]$metadata
named list()
```

I need to do something like this:

```
sparkData %>% mutate(CalculationList2 = fromJSON(CalculationList))
```

Where CalculationList is the string type I want to convert.

I'd be grateful for any kind of help!